# Getting values of a node using XPathNodeIterator

Tags: asp.net, xml, umbraco

Firstly apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere (I've searched!) but am stuck using an xPathNodeIterator in Umbraco for the first time.

Basically I've created a xPath Checkboxlist and I'm trying to get the values of what's been selected. What I've got (and this is the first time that I've used this, so most of this I've copied parrot fashion)

```
XPathNodeIterator n = umbraco.library.GetXmlNodeById(myNode.Id.ToString());
while (n.MoveNext())
{
    litSpeakers.Text += n.Current.InnerXml;
}
```

This returns me everything that's in the node content but I'm trying to just get the values of the XPath Checkboxlist (called xpather).

This is first time that I've used this and I'm clueless!! So if anyone could help that would be magic.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks for your response.

The way that I 'solved' it was (where 'speakers' is the name of the xpath checkboxlist)

```
        string dataValue = myNode.GetProperty("speakers").Value.ToString();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(dataValue);
        foreach (XmlNode itemnode in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
        {
            litNode.Text += itemnode.InnerText;
            Node myUmbracoNode = new Node(Int32.Parse(itemnode.InnerText));
            litNode.Text += myUmbracoNode.Name + "<br/>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but it should give you a pointer, checkboxes can use different 'truthy' values but I've assumed your checked ones have a value of "checked" rather than something else:

```
List<string> checkedNodes = new List<string>();

XPathNodeIterator n = umbraco.library.GetXmlNodeById(myNode.Id.ToString());
while (n.MoveNext())
{
  if (n.Current.GetAttribute("id","") == "xpather" && n.Current.GetAttribute("checked","") == "checked")
  {
    checkedNodes.Add("<something to identify whats been checked>");
  }
}
```

umbraco example: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getprevalues